# cascaded dropdown prepopulate knockout MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am on the Update details screen and I have a Country and a state dropdown .I want to pre populate State dropdown on the basis of the selected Country.
On the initial page load I do have the selected Country,Country Collection and Selected State all I need is to fetch the State Collection using AJAX.

```
Country List: <select id="CountryDropdownList" data-bind="options: viewModel.CountryCollection,optionsText:'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryName',value:viewModel.SelectedCountry"></select>
State List: <select id="StateDropdownList" data-bind="options: viewModel.StateCollection,optionsText:'StateName',optionsValue:'StateName',value:viewModel.SelectedState"></select>



 <script>
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
        console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); //State3 the initial value

        viewModel.SelectedCountry.subscribe(function (newSelectedCountry) {
            alert(newSelectedCountry);
            console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); //undefined why?
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetStateList?Country=' + newSelectedCountry,
                success: function (data) {
                    viewModel.StateCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
                    console.log(viewModel.SelectedState());  //state0 why?

                }
            })
        });


        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $(function () {
            viewModel.SelectedCountry.valueHasMutated();
        })

    </script>
```

But when I try to fetch the state list through AJAX request the Selected State value gets reset and the first value in the list becomes the default selected value. I am confused, why does KO update my selected State value when I am not changing it at all?

But if I set the Selected State again in AJAX Success callback it works fine

```
viewModel.SelectedCountry.subscribe(function (newSelectedCountry) {
            alert(newSelectedCountry);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetStateList?Country=' + newSelectedCountry,
                success: function (data) {
                    viewModel.StateCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.StateCollection)());
                    viewModel.SelectedState(data.SelectedState);

                }
            })
        });
```

I am looking for a reason for this strange behavior.

Comment: check you check logging the same thing before ajax call and see the o/p,

Comment: I just checked the value before the AJAX call and it is giving as undefined any idea what is going wrong here?

Comment: can anyway you can setup a fiddle which reproduces your issue . try moving `applyBindings` to `document.ready` code inside  and remove `viewModel.SelectedCountry.valueHasMutated();`  and try it

Comment: If I remove viewModel.SelectedCountry.valueHasMutated() then the subscription is not fired on load this is just to tell ko that this value has changed so fire the subscription

Comment: `viewModel.SelectedCountry.valueHasMutated()` you are calling on observable which is not needed (internally if there is a change it do the same) .

Comment: yes there should not be a need to add this method since we are using observable but the problem is that my ViewModel  initially has the country list so for KO there is no change in the value it is just initial binding so it is not firing the subscription method on it's own . For this reason I added the valueMutated method to make the subscription fire on load.

Comment: provide a jsfiddle which reproduces your issue. Building a view-model based in a string sent by the server is not a good practice. try to avoid this

Comment: Sure I will try to provide a Fiddle but may I ask why is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried simplifying the code as directed by you and now I think it might help you to point out the issue.

```
<script>
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
        console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); // o/p state3

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Home/GetStateList?Country=' + viewModel.SelectedCountry(),
            success: function (data) {
                viewModel.StateCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
                console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); // o/p state0
            }
        })
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    </script>
```

Comment: I am sorry but I have mentioned in the comments the value of selectedState it is still getting reset  to State0 after the ajax call. Any idea why?