# Knockout fire subscription on load for drop down change

Tags: javascript, .net, knockout.js

I have to use `valueHasMutated` method in ko to fire subscription on page load while binding Country list  dropdown so that I can fetch state on the basis of selected dropdown, is there an alternative to this ? How can I fire the country subscription without using this method ?

```
Country List: <select id="CountryDropdownList" data-bind="options: viewModel.CountryCollection,optionsText:'CountryName',optionsValue:'CountryName',value:viewModel.SelectedCountry"></select>
State List: <select id="StateDropdownList" data-bind="options: viewModel.StateCollection,optionsText:'StateName',optionsValue:'StateName',value:viewModel.SelectedState"></select>

<script>
        var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
        console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); //State3 the initial value

        viewModel.SelectedCountry.subscribe(function (newSelectedCountry) {
            alert(newSelectedCountry);
            console.log(viewModel.SelectedState()); //undefined why?
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/GetStateList?Country=' + newSelectedCountry,
                success: function (data) {
                    viewModel.StateCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data)());
                    console.log(viewModel.SelectedState());  //state0 why?

                }
            })
        });


        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $(function () {
           //to fire subscription
            viewModel.SelectedCountry.valueHasMutated();
        })

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that the problem is in attaching the event handler after the complete construction of the model object by calling fromJS.
All observables do already have their values set, so the subscribed function is not called without the manual call to valueHasMutated.

A solution could be by

- first creating the model, including the subscribe to the SelectedCountry observable.
- instantiate this model and set the observable values

This way the subscribed function will be called, because the handler is attached before values are set.

Comment: Exactly what is happening you have explained my problem pretty well but the solution you have provided is a all together a different approach , can you think of an alternative to fix it without using the mutated method in my scenario?Also state if you feel it is not possible  I shall mark it as your above explanation is pretty relevant.

Comment: No, I don't think it can be solved while using fromJS. You can't subscribe to observables being generated on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify `viewmodel.`on your bind variables in the HTML. When you call `ko.applyBindings`, it creates the default context for your bind variables.

If the values of the `value` bound variable doesn't match any of the options values, it will (by default) be set to undefined. This may be what is happening (see your "undefined why?" comment). Try adding the [valueAllowUnset](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html#using-valueallowunset-with-select-elements) option. I'm probably explaining this wrong. But you'll want to check the initial values against the options, at any rate.

Comment: yes you are right my bad. Any idea about the subscription issue ?

Comment: I had hoped that fixing the bind variables might address it. What are the default values of your select variables? Do they correctly match options values?

Comment: By default value do you mean oprtionCaption? I have tried adding it as optionCaption:"--select--", but even that does not fires the subscription.
And the data that is fetched in the initial load if you are refering that as default value then CountryCollection is an array of 10 countries like "CountryCollection": [{ "Id": 0, "CountryName": "Country0" }..] and "SelectedCountry": "Country3"

Comment: I mean is the initial value of `selectedCountry` definitely one of the `CountryName`s? See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Rou but I think Philip got it right and as far as the undefined is concerned I still do not have an answer for that I do have  separate thread for that 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31471897/cascaded-dropdown-prepopulate-knockout-mvc?noredirect=1#comment50915778_31471897
 
as directed by you I have checked the selected value do exists in the drop down so it is probably something else.

Comment: Adding the valueAllowUnset  = true, stoped the subscription working on the inital create, thanks